# Fancybox not centering correctly? (slightly to the left)

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox, center

See the following site:

http://goo.gl/wa41k

Click the invisible little white box just above the book image, below the title. When you see it, a fancybox will pop open with a flip book inside. The width of the fancybox is 900px.

If you shrink the window enough (around 950 will do), you'll see that there is no space left on the left side, while there's plenty enough on the right. This causes the left navigation button in the fancybox (for the flip book, you must turn to the third page to see the left nav button) to be cut off.

I should mention i'm using a fairly old version of Fancybox, because i am unable to upgrade (the site breaks). I'm using version 1.3.4.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm still unsure as to why it is pushed to the right, but i was able to solve it by pushing the element inside (`#fancybox-outer`) to the right a bit, to counter the left "push".

```
#fancybox-wrap #fancybox-outer { left: 20px; }
```